# How do you upgrade the tooling api client to a higher version in android studio? What does it mean?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I am working on a project and the android-studio version at my work is the latest 3.4.2

Today I pushed my project to Github to be able to work on it from home from my own system which has an android-studio version 2.2.2

I was making a clone of the project and after taking several minutes it gave the following error:

> Gradle Project Refresh Failed:
>
> ```
> Error:Support for clients using a tooling API version older than 3.0 was 
> removed in Gradle 5.0. You are currently using tooling API version 2.14.1. 
> You should upgrade your tooling API client to version 3.0 or later.
> ```

Looking at 2s and 3s I am guessing it has something to do with the version of android studio. But I don't even understand what is an API tooling client and where to look for it in Android Studio to upgrade? None of the project files actually loaded which means it has to be done something within the software in the settings but there's nothing in the gradle section.

I am hoping there must be a better solution than reinstalling the entire software. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting no answer here, I updated my android studio to the latest version, deleted the old project, made a clone again and this time it worked perfectly fine. I think directly updating the gradle plugin and the sdk tools would have worked too.